# flask-login check user_loader between three tables

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

I am using `Flask==1.0.2` and `Flask-Login==0.4.1`, I need to check the login (email and password) between three tables in `Postgres` Database, we are using `SQLAlchemy`, the three tables have the fields (email and password).

**tbl_employees**

**tbl_clients**

**tbl_partners**

But I'm having trouble using the three tables with:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user (user_id):
    return UserModel.get (user_id)
```

Comment: Is it actually essential to have your users in 3 separate tables? This seems very counterintuitive, usually you'd just have a "user" table with either a column for the user's category or a [role table](https://flask-user.readthedocs.io/en/latest/authorization.html) and association table which lets you tag each user with a set of roles.

Comment: Yes, the system already exists, we are working on the web portal for a single login.

Comment: I solved it, I reimplemented the method `get_id()` of Flask-Login getting the email parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I have 2 tables that contain user authentication info and was having trouble implementing `user_loader`. I used `session` to solve this problem:

**models.py**

```py
from flask_login import UserMixin

class lab_login(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(512), nullable=False)
    lab_name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    phone = db.Column(db.String(15))

class regular_login(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    phone = db.Column(db.String(15))
```

In the code below, the most important part is the `session['type'] = 'lab'` and `session['type'] = 'regular'`. For your case, you could swap out these values for employees/clients/partners.

**auth.py**

```py
@auth_bp.route("/lab", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def lab_login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form["email"]
        password = request.form["password"]

        lab = lab_login.query.filter_by(email = email).first()
        if lab:
            if check_password_hash(lab.password, password):
                login_user(lab, remember = False)
                session.permanent = True
                session['type'] = 'lab'
                flash('Login successful!', category='success')
                return redirect(url_for('views.index'))
            else:
                flash('Incorrect password. Please try again.', category = 'error')
        else:
            flash('That email is not associated with an account.', category = 'error')

    return render_template('lab_login.html', user = current_user)

@auth_bp.route("/regular", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def regular_login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form["email"]
        password = request.form["password"]

        user = regular_login.query.filter_by(email = email).first()
        if user:
            if check_password_hash(user.password, password):
                login_user(user, remember = True)
                session.permanent = True
                session['type'] = 'regular'
                flash('Login successful!', category = 'success')
                return redirect(url_for('views.index'))
            else:
                flash('Incorrect password. Please try again.', category = 'error')
        else:
            flash('That email is not associated with an account.', category = 'error')

    return render_template('user_login.html', user = current_user)
```

And now for the revised `user_loader` function:

**config.py**

```py
from flask import session
from flask_login import LoginManager

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    type = session.get('type')
    if type == 'lab':
        user = lab_login.query.filter_by(id = id).first()
    elif type == 'regular':
        user = regular_login.query.filter_by(id = id).first()
    else:
        user = None
    return user
```